# Adding text to an empty copied file using Robocopy

Tags: bash, robocopy

I have a script that copies all wildcard defined files from one place to another, and then an empty copy of each file to another location:

```
robocopy %copypath% %copypath_empty% *.DATAPUMP /MAXAGE:1 /create
```

My Question: How do I add arbitrary text into this blank file so that it is at least 1KB big..?

Comment: Create a dump file with 1KB size. Write a batch file in such a way that it will pick that file for all copy commands and rename it to the one you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /R %copypath_empty% %%f IN (*.DATAPUMP) DO ECHO TEXT >> %%f
```

Answer (score 0):

Might need to iterate over the files and append the text. I don't believe there is a function in robocopy that will do this. I'm not positive on the syntax.

```
for f in *.DATAPUMP
do
  "text" >> "$f"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this did not work. I did however manage to get a working solution - Please see my answer above